# AngularJS - Error Body Request POST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, post, activiti

I'm newbie to AngularJs, i need to do a post request on a server with enum form. I do this in this way in JS:

```
function completeTaskAction2($scope, $http, Base64) {
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode('kermit' + ':' + 'kermit');
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/runtime/tasks")
    .then(function (response, data, status, headers, config) {
        var ids = response.data.data[0].id;

        $scope.formData2 = {
            taskId: ids,
            properties: [{
                    id: 'requestApproval',
                    value: ''
            }
            ]
        }
    });
$scope.submitForm2 = function () {

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/form/form-data",
        data: angular.toJson($scope.formData2),
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Base64.encode('kermit' + ':' + 'kermit'),
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).success(function (data) {

        console.log("OK", data);
    }).error(function (data) {

        console.log("Error Posting data...");
        console.log(data);
        console.log($scope.submitForm2);
    });
};
```

};

and in html:

```
 <div ng-controller="completeTaskAction2">
                        <div ng-repeat="x in names">
                            {{ x.name }}*

                            <form ng-submit="submitForm2()">
                                <a ng-if="x.type=='enum'">
                                    <select ng-model="formData2.properties[0].value" ng-options="y.name for y in x.enumValues " placeholder="{{ x.name[0] }}"> {{ x.name }} </select>
                                </a>
                                <br>

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></span> Submit Enum!
                                </button>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    </form>
```

but i have this error:

> Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance …

and response body is:

```
{"taskId":"67762","properties":[{"id":"requestApproval","value":{"id":"true","name":"Yes"}}]}
```

I need to send only this to the server:

```
**{"taskId":"67762","properties":[{"id":"requestApproval","value":"true"}}]**
```

How i can do this?

Comment: You can try `data: $scope.formData2` instead of `data: angular.toJson($scope.formData2)`

Comment: @Nora thank you for reply! but same error and result... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ng-options should be like this:

```
ng-options="y.id as y.name for y in x.enumValues"
```

this will bind id of `y` to the model value instead of whole `y` object.

Comment: Thank You! Worked like a charm! I finally solved my problem! :D

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
<select ng-model="formData2.properties[0].value" ng-options="y.name for y in x.enumValues " placeholder="{{ x.name[0] }}"> {{ x.name }} </select>
```

You should use ng-selected like so:

```
<select ng-model="formData2.properties[0].value" ng-options="y.name for y in x.enumValues " ng-selected="x.name[0]"></select>
```

This should solve your problem but I can't test this right now unfortunately. Let me know if this solves your issue :)

Comment: unfortunately didn't work. Same error and result... :( Thanks anyway